# ASIHttpRequest login empty response

Tags: ios, ios4, asihttprequest

I have a request I would use ASIHttpRequest,for this page how can I do ?

```
            <form method="post" action="Login.jsp">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Insert</legend>
                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="username">User</label><input maxlength="10" id="user" name="username" value=""></li>
                        <li><label for="password">Password</label><input maxlength="16" type="password" id="pwd" name="password" value="" ></li>
                        <li id="errore"> error</li>
                        <li><input type="submit" id="go" value="enter"></li>

                    </ul>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

I have make this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url....Login.jsp"]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"user" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"pass" forKey:@"password"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];

 NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);
```

but i receive:
Response 0 ==> (null) 
I also used [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]; 
where is the mistake? And I also want to read the page that gives me to be logged. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should get the response and responseData from the Delegate...

Here is your code:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url....Login.jsp"]];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"user" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"pass" forKey:@"password"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(PostFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(PostFinished:)];

[request startSynchronous];
```

and in your main file add the 2 delegate methods:

```
- (void)PostFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{
    //notify user
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error sending request to the server" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)PostFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest
{  
    //get here your post response data...

    NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", theRequest.responseStatusCode, [theRequest responseString]);
}
```

Comment: Which asihttp delegate method does get called? The finished or failed ?

Comment: yes the url is correct, receive error from PostFailed. And thanks for reply. :)

Comment: well did you debug it? What does the error object report as an error? You should add a breakpoint in postFailed and in the gdb, enter po [error description]